# How to check if api-server insecure-port enabled in AKS

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-apiserver

I want to check if insecure-port is enabled or not in my Azure Kubernetes cluster. How can i do this.

Comment: As far as I checked [here](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/1724) `AKS clusters have the API insecure port disabled by default (--insecure-port=0)` and you should be able to confirm that with checking the value in `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml`. Let me know if that answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I checked [here](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/1724)

> AKS clusters have the API insecure port disabled by default (--insecure-port=0)

You should be able to confirm that with checking the `--insecure-port` value with

`sudo nano /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml`

Hope this answer your question, let me know if you have any questions.